# Singleton pattern reinstantiation

Tags: java

I am a bit confused, lets take this in Java:

```
public final class Singleton {
    private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

    private Singleton() {}

    public static Singleton getInstance() {
        return INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

I can easily keep recreating

```
Singleton one = new Singleton();
Singleton two = new Singleton();
Singleton three = new Singleton();
....
```

`

So what is the purpose of keeping only one instance if I can keep recreating?

Comment: "I can easily keep recreating" - did you try doing so, outside the class? (It's only the code *inside* the class that gets to enforce that it's a singleton.)

Comment: The question has a point, just the example given makes it less clear. Consider the singleton class is more complex with many lines of code. And the private constructor makes a change to the database for instance. As designer of the class you should make sure the developers maintaing your class will use it as intended, only calling the constructor once, even inside the class.

Comment: Constructors have no business changing the database, for instance. Constructors should _only_ initialize the object. Business logic belongs after the constructor finishes.

Comment: If you used the best-practice idiom for a singleton (single-constant enum) you wouldn't have this issue.

Comment: The question imo is how to prevent the given singleton implementation from being instatiated more than once. I was giving an example of a scenario where this concern might be legitimate. Enums are not a silver bullet, they have the drawback of being eagerly initialized for starters. But it is the most common implementation, I agree with you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the constructor in your example is `private`, specifically so you can't create multiple instances of that class, and only use `getInstance()` to obtain the single instance of that class.

Comment: This is something new I might learn today. If a constructor is private, is `Class c1 = new Class()` not valid?

Comment: @AdityaKalra A private constructor can only be accessed from within the body of the class of that constructor. Therefore `private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();` works (since it's inside the `Singleton` class), but from outside the `Singleton` class you can't invoke that constructor (unless you cheat with reflection).

Answer (score 1):

You can create Singletons only inside your singleton's class, because the constructor is private. When you want to get access to singleton's properties and methods from outside of that class, you use getInstance to get the reference to already existing singleton instead of creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

First off, as commentators pointed out, there are many things to keep in mind before deciding weather a singleton is the best way to go and then to decide on an implementation of the singleton: is your singleton's instantiation going to be heavy and is it not going to be always used or should you postpone instantiation until you need it? then go for lazy initialization instead of enums or your eager exaple; is your code multi-threaded? is your application distributed on a cluster for example? do you need to serialize the instance? etc. **Many times using the singleton is not the best answer**, it can make it hard to test and debug things. Here is [a good article discussing when not to use singleton](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/co-single/index.html).

If you decided a singleton is the answer, you have several implementation options based on how it is going to be used. See this [article describing various implementations and their drawbacks](http://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples#enum-singleton).

**Coming back to your question**: a eager initializing singleton class for which serialization and thread-safety are not a concern. As designer of the class you should make sure the developers maintaining your class will use it as intended, only calling the constructor once. Even from inside the class.

You can improve your code to make it obvious to anyone changing the class in the future that the constructor should only be called once. You could do something like this:

```
public final class Singleton {
private static final Singleton INSTANCE = new Singleton();

private Singleton() {
   if(INSTANCE != null){
      throw new RuntimeException("singleton constructor called twice");
   }
}

public static Singleton getInstance() {
    return INSTANCE;
   }
}
```

Moving away from your code more, you can create it with an enum:

```
public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;
    private Singleton(){
          //initializing
    }
    //public methods
}
```

Comment: This is a non-thread-safe, unnecessarily complicated implementation of singleton that is not immune to deserialization bugs.